# How to pass C++ classes as arguments when calling python functions from C++?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am writing a C++ application that needs load a Python module, and calls functions in that module.
The application needs to pass to the python function a C++ claseses as arguments.
I managed to call python code from the C++ code, but I only manage to pass "primative" types as arguments.

I create wrappers/interfaces using SWIG, but I failed to find how to convert my C++ class from the application to PyObject* in order to pass it as argument to the python functions.

Do you know where I can find information about how to perform the casting from C++ to PyObject*?

Answer (score 0):

Boost has a python interface library which might be helpful for you.

[check it out](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/index.html)

[heres the documentation on functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

I still dont have a solution, I only have the following workaround:
1. I create a PyObject from the instance, and pass it to the python function.
2. The python code, uses a function in the library that was generated by SWIG, to convert the PyObject to the python version of the class.

implementation:

In C++ file

```
MyClass myObject;
...
PyObject *parameterForPython = PyCObject_FromVoidPtr(&myObject, NULL); // step 1
PyTuple_SetItem(pyArgs, 0, parameterForPython);
PyObject_CallObject(pythonFunctionObject, pyArgs);
```

In swig interface file (code for step 2) :

```
%inline %{
    MyClass *convertPyObjectToMyClass(PyObject * ptr) {
        return (MyClass *)PyCObject_AsVoidPtr(ptr)
    }
%}
```

In python module:

```
def myPythonFunction(ptr):
    myObject = cppmodule.convertPyObjectToMyClass(ptr) #step 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to use `SWIG_NewPointerObj(ptr, type, flags)` or `SWIG_ConvertPtr(obj, pptr, type, flags)` ?

You can have those declarations by running:

```
swig -python -external-runtime swig-python.h
```